# tables have only that data which i add manualy not by insert query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [INSERT query, it returns 1 (1 row is inserted). But when I view the table, I see nothing. The return statement in the code below returns 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032374/insert-query-it-returns-1-1-row-is-inserted-but-when-i-view-the-table-i-see)

```
   string connectionString = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SAW - DB STORE.sdf",
   result = "";

            using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand())
                {
                    com.CommandText = "INSERT  INTO Words (Word, Word_Length, Bonus_Word, Points) VALUES (@wrd, @len, @bnus_wrd, @points)";

                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wrd", wrd);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@len", len);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bnus_wrd", bnus_wrd);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@points", points);

                    com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                    com.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();

                    try
                    {
                        int r = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        result = string.Format("{0} WORD ADDED", r);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        result = string.Format("Error found: {0}", ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            label7.Visible = true;
            label7.Text = result;



            SqlCeConnection con1 = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SAW - DB STORE.sdf");
            con1.Open();
            SqlCeCommand com1 = new SqlCeCommand();
            com1.CommandText = "Select * From Words";
            com1.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            com1.Connection = con1;
            SqlCeDataReader read;
            read = com1.ExecuteReader();
            while (read.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Text =" + read[1]);
            }
            con1.Close();
```

tables have only that data which i add manualy not by insert query?
 using visual studio 2012
data should be in table but is not if added through insert query

Comment: Well, what is the value of r?

Comment: R is the count of effected rows

Comment: i recieve the data inserted in message box in code but is not visible in table

Comment: Are you getting the data in MessageBox That you have inserted?If You are getting the inserted data that means simply you have inserted right.

Comment: yes insert is working i think but data is not written in tables

Comment: INSERT statement affects 1 row, but the VS Server Explorer shows that it doesn't actually update the SQL CE database

Comment: Could you tell me if your SDF file is included in your project? And if it is included in your project what is the value for the property `Copy To The Output Directory`?

Answer (score 0):

Use try and catch and put debugger at ExecuteNonQuery.Problem is with your AddWithValue,Rest Everything is fine..In AddwithValueThere is no type checking. Potentially, that could lead to errors if you try to provide a value that doesn't fit the target database column's data type.Better to use Parameters.Add.Like this way

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int));

cmd.Parameters["@Id"].Value = 1;

Comment: i was doing that before but not working

Comment: Just Close your DataBase and Again Open it.Everything is fine.Check It.

Comment: no the tables are empty then how evrything is fine

Comment: If you are getting back the inserted data,that means data is in table.Use Some Logic and mind.

Comment: INSERT statement affects 1 row, but the VS Server Explorer shows that it doesn't actually update the SQL CE database

Comment: data is not visible in Server Explorer

Answer (score 0):

If everything with the insertion seems to work but you still can't see the data in Server Explorer then you are probably looking at the wrong database/file in the Server Explorer.